# Editing multiple variables inside multiple lists in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

If i have a list as follows:

```
[['New York', '0.0', '5.0'], ['Boston', '10.2', '0.0'], ['Tokyo', '11.5', '3.3'], ['Paris', '9.5', '4.8']]
```

How can I remove all the first variables (cities) in the lists, so that I end up with this:

```
[['0.0', '5.0'], ['10.2', '0.0'], ['11.5', '3.3'], ['9.5', '4.8']]
```

If the values would be inputed, would it affect the way I would have to do it, since the amount of lists and variables would be different each time?

Comment: I am sure this exact question was asked before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list slicing and comprehension to make a new list.

```
list_one = [['New York', '0.0', '5.0'], ['Boston', '10.2', '0.0'], ['Tokyo', '11.5', '3.3'], ['Paris', '9.5', '4.8']]
[item[1:] for item in list_one]
```

Output:

```
[['0.0', '5.0'], ['10.2', '0.0'], ['11.5', '3.3'], ['9.5', '4.8']]
```

Using `[1:]` takes every element from position 1 onwards (i.e. everything but the first element)

Comment: There's a typo in your explanation, I think you meant ``[1:]`` instead of ``[:1]``.

Comment: @DocDriven Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
L = [['New York', '0.0', '5.0'], ['Boston', '10.2', '0.0'],
     ['Tokyo', '11.5', '3.3'], ['Paris', '9.5', '4.8']]

res = [i[1:] for i in L]
```

Functionally, you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = list(map(list, map(itemgetter(1, 2), L)))
```

Result:

```
[['0.0', '5.0'], ['10.2', '0.0'], ['11.5', '3.3'], ['9.5', '4.8']]
```